# Delete using a composite key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, delete

I am trying to wrap my head around creating a delete statement for a table with a composite key.

I would like to create something like:

```
DELETE 
FROM 
    table_example1
WHERE
    COLUMN1, COLUMN2
    IN
    (SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM table_example2
    WHERE
        COLUMN_DATETIME > @Period);
```

Keeping in mind only the combination of `COLUMN1` and `COLUMN2` is unique, each column on its own is not unique.

I can't seem to get my head around how I would actually do this.

Comment: According to the SQL standard you need parentheses around the columns: `where (COLUMN1, COLUMN2)  IN  (...)` but I don't think SQL server supports this.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I had found this online as well, but SQL server indeed does not support this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
DELETE A
FROM 
    table_example1 AS A
    INNER JOIN table_example2 AS B
    ON A.COLUMN1 =B.COLUMN1
    AND A.COLUMN2 = B.COLUMN2
WHERE
    COLUMN_DATETIME > @Period;
```

Alternatively:

```
DELETE FROM A
FROM dbo.table_example1 AS A
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.table_example2 AS B
    WHERE
        B.COLUMN1 = A.COLUMN1
        AND B.COLUMN2 = A.COLUMN2
        AND B.COLUMN_DATETIME > @Period
);
```