# Exclude composite key from select

Tags: select

I have 2 identical DBs, one of the tables has C1, C2, C3 , composite key.
I'm trying to get the rows from B that are not present in DB A.

I have tried many approaches, but at this time I even can't re-use this [suggestion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/100845/delete-using-a-composite-key) due too the late hour.

I think it should be by something like

```
Select * from B
where  not exists                
     (SELECT a.C1, a.C2, a.C3
      from A.table as a, b.table as b 
      where a.C1=b.C1
          , a.C2=b.C2
          , a.C3=b.C3)
```

But I know that I'm totally wrong.
What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: *one of the tables has C1, C2, C3 , composite key* You mean it's **primary** key of the table? or simply the table' structure contain index composed from those 3 fields?

Comment: Yes they are a primary key, but the question is valid even if they weren't.

Comment: For contextualization, after I tested the two answers I was still having unexpected results. My root error was on identifying the correct fields that composed the key while working late night. None the less, my bad foundations only bring doubts. The good answers, like @4per's, bring knowledge

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Even if this seems very basic SQL, `not in` with multiple columns isn't supported by all DBMSes, so it's helpful to know which you're using.

Comment: I was using MS SQL Manager

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
Select * from b.table as b 
where  not exists                
     (SELECT 1
      from A.table as a 
      where a.C1=b.C1 and a.C2=b.C2 and a.C3=b.C3 ) ;
```

1. You shouldn't add `b.table` in the subquery's `from` clause, because you already have it under the `b` alias in the main query.
2. You don't need to specify columns in the subquery's `select` clause, because that doesn't have any effect. "Is there a row satisfying the `where` clause?" – that's the question that the `exists` predicate is meant to answer.
3. You need `AND` between the conditions in `WHERE`, not commas.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I needed. As for the 2) You have teach me the "select 1",  was really lost there.

Answer (score 4):

Historically, DBMSes had trouble with `NOT IN`. But most DBMSes today can handle it without problem. Not all DBMSes support this syntax with multiple columns (SQL Server doesn't for example), but many do (PostgreSQL, Oracle, MySQL). This should work for those (but untested):

```
SELECT *
FROM b.table
WHERE (c1, c2, c3) NOT IN (SELECT c1, c2, c3 FROM a.table);
```

Answer (score 3):

To find rows in B that are not present in A you can `LEFT JOIN` A to B:

```
SELECT w.* 
  FROM      B.table AS w
  LEFT JOIN A.table AS z ON z.C1 <=> w.C1
                        AND z.C2 <=> w.C2
                        AND z.C3 <=> w.C3
 WHERE z.C1 IS NULL
   AND z.C2 IS NULL
   AND z.C3 IS NULL
;
```

Here I suppose that no record have C1, C2 and C3 all equal to NULL.
`LEFT JOIN` substitute missed/nonexistent rows from A.table by rows filled by nulls that allow to distinguish them by `WHERE`.

P.S.
As suggested by [ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9) when rows joined on with plain `=` NULLs are irrelevant, but also any row containing `NULL` in C1 or C2 or C3 column will be rejected from the resulting set. That happens because `ON` require `TRUE` for each condition used, while `A=B` return `NULL` (not `TRUE`) if any operand is `NULL`. Therefore null-safe comparison `<=>` should be used instead of `=`.

Comment: Thanks, this also works (and I din't had any null)

Comment: Nulls are irrelevant. The query works whether there are nulls or not in C1/C2/C3 columns.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Yep, null-safe `<=>` may cause the false results.

Answer (score 1):

SQL has the EXCEPT clause. It removes all rows from the first set which are also present in the second set.

```
select c1, c2, c3 from B.table
except
select c1, c2, c3 from A.table
```

One difficult bit is that all columns are compared, so if further values are required for subsequent processing this fragment has to be in a sub-select with an additional JOIN. As you may guess this can lead to many table operations and performance difficulties.

I add this for information only. My choice would be the NOT EXISTS form.

Comment: A disadvantage of this is that we can't see other columns from B (and the implicit DISTINCT means that it may return different number of rows than the NOT EXISTS method, unless (c1,c2,c3) is the PK in B).

Answer (score -6):

[image]This might be the simplest code to be written

```
select * 
from b
where b.c1+b.c2+b.c3 not in (select a.c1+a.c2+a.c3 from a)
```

If column values are int try using convert for them: 
`convert(varchar,b.c1)`

Comment: *if column values are int try using convert for them.* You think it prevents implicit type conversion back to INT? It's in vain...

Comment: It may be simple but adding the 3 values is not correct way to compare triplets. This would match `(1,2,3)` with `(3,1,2)` and even `(4,1,1)` and `(6,0,0)`

Comment: It may be simple but adding the 3 values is not correct way to compare triplets. This would match (1,2,3) with (3,1,2) and even (4,1,1) and (6,0,0)

it wont, check my screenshot for example. @ypercubeᵀᴹ

please change your votes if you agreed.

Comment: @Akina check my screenshot. it wont convert back when explicitly converted. 

please change your votes if you agreed.

Comment: You are assuming varchar columns, so the `+` is doing concatenation, not addition. If your answer meant that assumption, it should have been explained (that it only works by using VARCHARs (or converting columns to VARCHARs first).

Comment: Still it would fail for various reasons. Even for varchar columns, this would match `('1', '2', '34')`  with `('1', '23', '4')` and `('12', '3', '4')`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ i have already asked to convert if your datatype is int.

Comment: The topicstarter do not specify his RDBMS, while Your solution is RDBMS-dependent. It fails in MySQL, for example.

Comment: Still it would fail for various reasons. Even for varchar columns, this would match ('1', '2', '34') with ('1', '23', '4') and ('12', '3', '4')

agreed! thanks for the correction @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Comment: Also what @Akina commented. `CONVERT()` is not standard syntax (seems you are using SQL Server). The question has not been tagged so we don't know the DBMS.